# How to proof curvature and torsion are independent

Tags: curvature

As we know that curvature describes the change of curve in tangent and normal plane, while torsion describes the change the curve in binomial and normal plane. Assume we have a trajectory with length of $T$, then we can compute its curvature and torsion at time $t$ as $\kappa(t)$ and $\tau(t)$, how can we prove that $\kappa(t)$ and $\tau(t)$ are independent? Or since they are scale, it is not necessary to prove?

Thank you

Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy to prove that curvature and torsion are independent by looking at the curves
$$
\gamma_{a,b} = C(a \cos t, a \sin t, bt)
$$
where $C = \frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}$. The curvature and torsion for this curve are both constant, and the (constant) torsion depends only on $b$, and hence can be varied independently of the curvature.

If you mean the curvature and torsion at a particular point $t$ are "independent," I think I need to know more clearly what your notion of "independence" is.

Comment: Hi John, thank you for your reply. My independent is for $\kappa$ and $\tau$, not for a particular time $t$. Your first half answered my question. Just wondering if we can have a more general proof, instead of an equation based one.

Comment: Rene's answer points to the more general proof, but if you want to know things are independent, an example showing it seems like the simplest possible demonstration. (At least to me!)

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental theorem of curve theory says that if $\kappa(s) >0$ and $\tau(s)$ are given differentiable functions then there is a regular curve with  $\kappa(s)$ and $\tau(s)$ as curvature and torsion.